# Configure Unit testing for DAO Layer with Hibernate in SpringBoot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, junit

I've created an application using Springboot and Hibernate and i want to configure unit testing for it.

first this is the DAO interface.

```
public interface OrderDetailsDao {
    void createOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails);
    void updateOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails);
    void deleteOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails);
}
```

this is the DAO interface implemnetation

```
public class OrderDetailsDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements OrderDetailsDao {

    public void createOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails){
        getHibernateTemplate().save(orderDetails);
    }

    public void updateOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails){
        getHibernateTemplate().save(orderDetails);
    }

    public void deleteOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails){
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(orderDetails);
    }
}
```

Then I have created a test class as the following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrderDetailsDaoTest {

    OrderDetails orderDetails = new OrderDetails();

    @Autowired
    OrderDetailsDao orderDetailsDao;

    @Test
    public void testCreateOrder(){
        orderDetails.setValue(101.91);
        orderDetailsDao.createOrder(orderDetails);
    }
}
```

I have put the application.properties file in resources of both test and src directories.

i tried to run this unit test case, but it fails because of the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abdul.epl.repo.OrderDetailsDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So could i know please the best way to configure the unit test for the DAO layer?

Comment: You haven't shared enough information about your application. Where is `OrderDetailsDaoImpl` configured as a Spring bean? Do you expect it to be found by component scanning or an `@Bean` method on a `@Configuration` class? A [complete minimal example](/help/mcve) would make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate your test class with @SpringBootTest to tell Spring Boot to make the Spring application context (and hence all the Spring beans) available to the tests. Additionally you should use the SpringRunner instead of SpringJunit4ClassRunner with Spring Boot. i.e.:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderDetailsDaoTest {
```

If this still doesn't work you may need to directly specify where the configuration class that includes the component scanning that scans for your DAO class can be found using the @ContextConfiguration annotation. However this should not normally be required when using Spring Boot.